# Rundeck is not showing docker containers in nodes

Tags: docker, rundeck

I am using docker container plugin in rundeck. I was successfully able to start a ubuntu container in rundeck. As per the Rundeck plugin documentation, rundeck wil automatically detect the running container and will add same as a node in nodes tab.

But this is not happening in my case. can someone please advise on this ?

i have also configured the resource model source for docker but its still not showing.

Comment: Can you post the plugin documentation?

Comment: please find it here https://www.rundeck.com/blog/introduction-to-docker-plugins-for-rundeck?success=true